# setting cookie through jsp

Tags: jsp, cookies

When I am setting the cookie through JSP using the below code:

```
String username = userinfoid;
Cookie testcoo  = new Cookie ("username",username);
```

it is setting the cookie with value "zahidansari" (note value is with double quotes). Although value is correct it is bounded inside double quotes.

However when I am setting the cookie using the below code:

```
Cookie testcoo  = new Cookie ("username",username);
```

It is setting the cookie without the quotes.

I want the cookie value to be without the quotes. Does anybody have any idea why this is happening.

Comment: does it happens in all browsers?

Comment: checked in chrome. Let me check in others

Comment: checked in chrome, mozilla . Happening in both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got the same problem. Not to leave this question unanswered :) this is my workaround:

Encode cookie value:

```
String username = userinfoid;
Cookie testcoo  = new Cookie ("username", URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8"));
```

For more information take a look [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572482/why-do-cookie-values-with-whitespace-arrive-at-the-client-side-with-quotes)