# Android: BasicClientCookie/CookieStore adds quotes around cookie value

Tags: java, android, cookies, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm using the following snippet of code to add a cookie to an http request in Android, sent using Android's DefaultHttpClient:

```
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
BasicClientCookie2 cookie = new BasicClientCookie2("AUTH_TOKEN", "MY_TOKEN");
cookie.setVersion(1);
cookie.setDomain("my.domain.com");
cookie.setPath("/");
cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);

context.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
```

When I look at the received cookie value on the server, I get

```
Cookie: $Version=1; AUTH_TOKEN="MY_TOKEN"
```

but what I am expecting is (notice the missing quotes):

```
Cookie: $Version=1; AUTH_TOKEN=MY_TOKEN
```

Unfortunately, the extra quotes causes the server (which I don't manage) to choke, and completely ignore the cookie.

I tried using `BasicClientCookie` instead of `BasicClientCookie2` with no luck. Is there a fix for this or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, calling `cookie.setVersion(0);` on the Cookie should fix this, as quotes are invalid in version 0 of the cookie spec according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7233959/473637).

In my case, since this was the only cookie I had to send with the request, I simply added it as a header myself:

> post.addHeader("Cookie", "AUTH_TOKEN=" + myAuthToken);

Answer (score 0):

RFC 6265:

```
cookie-header = "Cookie:" OWS cookie-string OWS
cookie-string = cookie-pair *( ";" SP cookie-pair )
cookie-value = *cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )
```

So user-agent MAY place quotes around value.