# How to set cookie value with whitespace without quotes

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cookies

I know that according to the documentation, cookie values should not contain white space, and I've already read this topic 
[Why do cookie values with whitespace arrive at the client side with quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572482/why-do-cookie-values-with-whitespace-arrive-at-the-client-side-with-quotes/)

But I still have a problem with it. I get cookie value

*emailAddress=john.doe@mail.com&firstName=John&authenticationExpiresUTC=12/05/2014 10:41:35*

I need to change some information in them and then return cookie in the same format, because the other services expects it to be so.

The services is .NET, I don't even have access to them. So, I can't change anything in their code, and use URL-encode/decode or something like this.

Is there any solution of the problem?
Thanks in advance.

**EDITED:** I should set edited cookie value in Java.

Comment: u can encode the value before adding it in the cookie

Comment: @Arvind when I tryied it, the cookie looks such like this emailAddress%3Djohn.doe%40mail.com%26firstName%3DJohn%26authenticationExpiresUTC%3D11%2F05%2F2014+13%3A43%3A42 If other services was Java, it would not cause any issues to decode this value. But  right now .Net service expects cookie in a format without encoded charecters.

Comment: Hope this will Help :) By encoding the value  [Encode URI][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444112/how-do-i-encode-uri-parameter-values

Comment: @Jane where exactly r u facing problem in updating value of cookie?

Comment: @Arvind In Java. When add edited cookie value, it appears in quotes.